# Do these phrases add value to these sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, sentence

1. Let’s hope for *coronavirus free* 2021
2. More than 1.7 million people have lost *their valuable lives (life?)* in the COVID-19 pandemic, so far.

Although I would like to know if both are grammatically correct or not. But my main question is about those highlighted phrases.

Will people understand what I mean by coronavirus free? (I want to say let's hope covid-19 cases will decrease)

In 2nd sentence, I want to say that all the people who lost their life (lives?) had their own dreams, values etc. I mean they were as important as living ones. Their deaths shouldn't go waste, current and future generations can learn lessons from the pandemic and deaths. So I added the word "valuable". Is it okay to write like that?

Comment: In the first example, 'a' should precede corona virus free 2021, like "Let’s hope for a corona-virus free 2021"  2) So far, more than 1.7 million people have lost their valuable life in the COVID-19 pandemic.

Comment: @RamPillai thanks. "during the COVID-19 pandemic" will also be correct?

Comment: 'During' refers to a period, which 'Covid' is not.

Comment: @RamPillai "due to the COVID-19 pandemic"?

Comment: I just realised "in the pandemic" means there can be multiple reasons for deaths. I want to cover only covid deaths.

Comment: *So I added the word "valuable". Is it okay to write like that?* No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, you have a compound adjective which, according to the rules in the [Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/public-affairs/style-guide) (p 14) (to cite a typical source), should be hyphenated.

Furthermore, the term needs an article - the underlying sense is for 'a particular quality to 2021 which is coronavirus-free'.

Therefore, I would recommend you change it to:

**Let’s hope for a coronavirus-free 2021.**

Your second sentence relates to a question which has already been answered on the site - you should find an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12539/many-lost-their-life-or-many-lost-their-lives).

Comment: Thanks. I found my answer to lives/life doubt. But valuable lives is okay to use?

Comment: Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: good question. Actually, by using valuable, I feel some people might say everyone's life is valuable and it is automatically understood, so it would be like giving special/exaggerated emphasis to it. Isn't it?

Comment: Your question touches on philosophy rather than grammar - all life, or human life? (The idea that life is valuable should arguably be universal, but it isn't clear cut - we kill to eat, for instance; death sustains life.) We feel injustice when a healthy life is cut short early; it's not so clear cut when quality of life is reduced so much that a person could arguably be said to be better off dead - there is no consensus here. And any meaningful debate on life has to centre on a definition of life - a student of mine recently wrote an essay on this arguing intriguingly that life = time.